# NodeJs deployment on cPanel: Missing Passenger.log and stderr.log files

Tags: node.js, deployment, cpanel, web-deployment, logfile

I've deployed my NodeJs application on two different shared web hosting servers. The first one automatically generates stderr.log file and has a passenger file. However, the second server doesn't and I am therefore unable to see the error of the deployment. I've looked online but I couldn't find anything that can resolve my issue. I have also contacted the servers' customer service but they are not very helpful. Please let me know how can I create the stderr.log or passenger.log files! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Had to add the following into the startup file (e.g. `app.js`) in order to generate the error logs. Didn't need to do this on the other server provider as it's default in their system.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags : 'w'});
var log_stdout = process.stdout;
var log_stderr = process.stderr;

console.log = function(d) { //
  log_file.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stdout.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
  log_stderr.write(util.format(d) + '\n');
};

// var out = fs.openSync('./output.log', 'a')
//   , err = fs.openSync('./error.log', 'a');

// require('child_process').spawn('./server', [], {
//     detached    : true,
//     stdio       : ['ignore', out, err]
// });

var access = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/stdout.log', {flags : 'w'});
process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = access.write.bind(access);

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.error((err && err.stack) ? err.stack : err);
});
```

Comment: Works nicely, good solution. Passenger logs are not supported everywhere on Cpanel this is very helpful.